# Свободное место на диске С:

Tags: windows-10, hdd, ssd

[image: Здесь видно, что занято 81ГБ на диске]
[image: Здесь же открыв окно свойств, видно, что занято 56ГБ]

Все скрытые папки открыл. Куда делись еще 25ГБ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В корне диска есть системные файлы, которых обычным выделением и просмотром размера не найдете.

```
Загрузитесь с LiveCD -> Зайдите в диск С, и ВУАЛЯ.
```

Можете удалить если сильно нужен место на диске, НО винда не запуститься на 100%. XD.

Дополняю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Узнайте больше [тут](https://windowsnotes.ru/other/skrytye-i-sistemnye-fajly-windows/).

Comment: То есть те 25ГБ, это потерянное место?

Comment: Это не потерянное место, это скрытые системные файлы, которых Microsoft закрыла от вида, для того чтобы обычные пользователи не удалили чтобы освободить места и при следующей загрузки системы столкнулись с проблемами загрузки системы.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не пытайся понять. Просто прими это. Винда - темная штука. Возможно в System Volume Information много забито - это частое явление. Ты не можешь определить его размер - туда не пустит даже под админом. Разве что с livecd загрузиться и глянуть. Но лучше не заморачиваться.